# Cumulative sales measure - FILTER ( ALL('Date'), 'Date'[Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date] ))

Tags: database, reporting-services, powerbi, dax

I am a beginner in power BI and I need help on this.
What does mean this function in Power BI(what is the outcome) and how does it work?

```
FILTER ( ALL('Date'), 'Date'[Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date] ))
```

My thoughts are that this DAX function is filtering all data from the date table and gives back all dates from the date table except the latest date?

```
FILTER ( ALL('Date'), 'Date'[Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date] ))
```

Answer (score 0):

First things, expression below is returning a table, then you can read it like this :

```
   Table =
    FILTER (
    /*Take all the date in Date table*/
        ALL ( 'Date' ); 
    /* Then return all the date passing this condition*/
        'Date'[Date]<= **MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
    enter code here

 /*Whereas MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) is evaluating in the current filter context */
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FILTER` function takes a table as its first argument, iterates through each row checking whether the expression given as the second argument is true or false, and returns the table with only the rows where the expression evaluates to `TRUE()`.

The `ALL` function removes all filter and row context to return the entire table specified. Without this, the date table as the first argument would be filtered. You want the whole thing in this case.

In contrast, `MAX` is evaluated *within* the local filter context, so `MAX('Date'[Date])` returns the latest date within that context, which isn't necessarily the same as the latest date in the whole table.

So to get the cumulative sales measure, you get the latest date in the filter context using `MAX` and then filter the date table to include all dates up to and including that date.